# Writing Data to Oracle DB Server from R

Tags: c#, r, oracle, rjdbc

I'm trying to develop a simple R application suing R.NET; gets data from Oracle DB Server, make some modification and  write Results to a new Column.

I'm using RJDBC to Connect to Oracle DB Server.

I couldn't find a way to write data from R DataFrame to Oracle Server. I tried

```
dbWriteTable(oracleConnectionTarget, targetData, "SUVAR_LT", append = TRUE)
```

but it gives me "method getTables with signature (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/ResultSet; not found" error

Below is my code

```
library(RJDBC)
drv<-JDBC('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 'C:\\ojdbc6.jar')
conn<-dbConnect(drv,'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:eaorcl','testUsr','testPwd')
testData<-dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE")
... Codes that are manipulating testData and adding result column to testData
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Does `dbWriteTable(oracleConnectionTarget, "SUVAR_LT", targetData, append = TRUE)` work?  Or does [this Oracle forum thread](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2450460?start=0&tstart=0) help?

Comment: [This r-bloggers post may also be helpful](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-to-oracle-database-connectivity-use-roracle-for-both-performance-and-scalability/)

Comment: While R.NET may be in the mix of you solution, it looks like for your issue the tag 'java' is more relevant than c#